# How to use nslookup to query the following informations

Tags: networking, dns

On linux, when I hit `man nslookup` a lot of things say: not implemented. I'm wondering how to use `nslookup` program to fetch the following informations:

- 1) my local DNS server
- 2) DNS servers for some site(e.g. google.com,    facebook.com)
- 3) How to query for Type A, NS, CNAME, MX RRs?

Comment: Do you have to use nslookup? Could you use dog instead?

Comment: If you can show me all the answers for above, then why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that NSLOOKUP or Dig can provide your local DNS servers, as this is an OS call.  This is (usually) most easily done by

```
cat /etc/resolv.conf
```

on unix systems, however it looks like doing an nslookup will tell you the nameserver used for the query, so

```
 nslookup google.com
```

will return a "Server:" line which has the server IP which was queried.

To query DNS servers for a site using your local nameservers -

```
dig sitename.com ns
```

You can do the same thing using other nameservers (as long as those nameservers will allow you to do the lookup) by using @domain name - for example dig @8.8.8.8 facebook.com NS will tell you Facebooks nameservers according to the nearest Google Nameserver.    You could also do dig com NS to find a list on nameservers for .com domain names, then query one of those nameservers to see what the authorative nameservers think.

To query a record type

```
dig sitename.com RECORDtype
```

For example dig sitename.com MX will show you the MX records for the site, or dig sitename.com A will provide the A record(s).

Comment: This is a perfect answer for the question. But as a side request since I can't post this on this site, do you recommend any resources to practically approach computer networking which supplements ONLY theory side that computer degree pursuing students face?

Answer (score 1):

Got to love auto-correct. The utility that davidgo was referring to is called dig. For example, looking up SIP SRV records in Linux would be done using: `dig SRV _sip._tcp.domain.com`

Comment: What is SIP/SRV Records?

Comment: If possible could you please answer the three bullets in my question above?

Comment: I work in the telecommunications industry, so that is my most frequently used record type. However, for what you want to achieve you can replace SRV with the record type that you desire e.g. dig domain.com MX. More examples can be found here: https://www.linux.com/learn/check-your-dns-records-dig

Comment: What about my local DNS server and other sites'  DNS servers?

Comment: I need some clarification on points 1 & 2. Are you trying to figure out what your local DNS server is or are you trying to force a lookup to utilize your local DNS server? Are you trying to identify the name servers that somebody else is using?

Comment: I am trying to figure out what my local DNS server is and what are the DNS servers that some other sites e.g. google.com are using.